# Тестирование URI

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito, uri

Здравствуйте! Есть класс-роутер, который проверяет URI и на его основании составляет внутренний маршрут в системе. Столкнулся с проблемой при тестировании этого класса. Его единственный публичный метод принимает HttpServletRequest. Хотелось бы протестировать этот метод на правильность входящего URI. В объекте запроса есть возможность читать URI, но нет возможности его менять, поэтому нельзя и протестировать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно при тестировании задавать свой URI.
Тестирую с помощью jUnit и Mockito. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строго говоря, если ваш класс занимается разбором URI, то и на вход он должен принимать не запрос целиком, а только URI. Но конкретно данная задача легко решается с помощью Mockito: все что вам нужно - это создавать мок интерфейса на каждый тестируемый URI:

```
public class RouterTest {
    @Test
    public void shouldRouteToExpectedPaths() {
        Map<String, String> routes = new HashMap<>();
        routes.put("/product", "products");
        routes.put("/product/{id}", "single-product");
        routes.put("/about", "about");

        Router router = new Router(routes);
        router.setFallbackRoute("404");

        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("/product", "products");
        parameters.put("/product/12", "single-product");
        parameters.put("/about", "about");
        parameters.put("/non-existent", "404");

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : parameters.entrySet()) {
             HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
             Mockito.when(request.getRequestURI()).thenReturn(pair.getKey());
             assertEquals(pair.getValue(), router.route(request));
        }
    }
}
```

Писал все прямо в форме so, так что возможны небольшие ошибки. Параметры, конечно, лучше описывать не прямо в методе, а воспользоваться любым способом, сообщающим эти параметры тесту "снаружи" (JUnit parameters, JUnitParamsRunner, etc.).